# replacement NIC for intel 5100 going against dir-655 router

Tags: wireless-networking

I've got an intel 5100 on board with my T400 and I suspect it's the culprit in fluctuating wireless speeds, as I don't have the same problems with any other network devices and this thing is practically in line of sight with my router (dir-655).

Can I add a PCMCia network card for wireless instead? What can be added to a T400? What is the highest rated card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the intel 12.3 and above drivers (especially the new 13.x series) seems to have fixed many issues we were having with XP and our wireless network.  The Windows 7 built in driver is based off the older drivers.. (can't remember, recently got a T410) and we had some improvements by installing intel's newest driver on it as well.

That along with the Device manager power settings mentioned in the other answer.  Also, toss Access Connections if you use it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would double check, it is most likely an [ExpressCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard) socket you have and not PCMCIA.

You should be able to get a Wireless N card without problems in this which will get the most out of your router.

However, I would first check device manager and look at your network card to make sure it is not in a power save mode / it is set to maximum signal strength and also if you have the ability to open the laptop, make sure that the Aerial is plugged in to the card and not loose.